# Xamarin app missing com.google.android.things.jar support library

Tags: java, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, iot

I'm building a Xamarin app which I want to run on an Android Things Raspberry Pi device. I've installed via `adb` and the device starts but the app won't `logcat` shows the following:

> 11-09 18:38:55.653  1283  1283 E AndroidRuntime:
>   java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
>   dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/system/framework/com.google.android.things.jar", zip file
>   "/oem/app/main.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/oem/lib/main,
>   /system/fake-libs, /oem/app/main.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib,
>   /system/vendor/lib, /system/lib, /system/vendor/lib]]] couldn't find
>   "libmonodroid.so" 11-09 18:38:55.653  1283  1283 E AndroidRuntime:    at
>   java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:1011) 11-09 18:38:55.653 
>   1283  1283 E AndroidRuntime:  at
>   java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1657) 11-09 18:38:55.653 
>   1283  1283 E AndroidRuntime:  at
>   mono.MonoPackageManager.LoadApplication(MonoPackageManager.java:34)
>   11-09 18:38:55.653  1283  1283 E AndroidRuntime:  at
>   mono.MonoRuntimeProvider.attachInfo(MonoRuntimeProvider.java:22) 11-09
>   18:38:55.653  1283  1283 E AndroidRuntime:    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6285)
>   11-09 18:38:55.653  1283  1283 E AndroidRuntime:  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5851)
>   11-09 18:38:55.653  1283  1283 E AndroidRuntime:  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5772)
>   11-09 18:38:55.653  1283  1283 E AndroidRuntime:  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0) 11-09 18:38:55.653
>   1283  1283 E AndroidRuntime:  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1661)
>   11-09 18:38:55.653  1283  1283 E AndroidRuntime:  at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 11-09
>   18:38:55.653  1283  1283 E AndroidRuntime:    at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 11-09 18:38:55.653  1283  1283
>   E AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541) 11-09
>   18:38:55.653  1283  1283 E AndroidRuntime:    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 11-09 18:38:55.653 
>   1283  1283 E AndroidRuntime:  at
>   com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
>   11-09 18:38:55.653  1283  1283 E AndroidRuntime:  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)

I have installed `Xamarin.Android.Things` from nuget but this error still exists.

How do I include this jar in my apk from Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error with another library and I had to include all **Supported ABIs** under *Droid Project Options* -> *Android Build* -> *Configuration: Release* or *Debug* -> *Advanced*

[image]